# Hide Row from table when delete Query success with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to hide row from while loop. I want to hide full row when delete query success. Delete query is working fine need help to hide row. Thanks in advance.

While loop Code :

While Loop is working fine. Should i add any class to row for deleting. $chcrsid is unique.

```
    while ($rowslctd=mysql_fetch_array($resultslctd))

{

    $chcrs=$rowslctd['chcrs'];
    $chcrsid=$rowslctd['chcrsid'];



echo"<tbody><tr>
<td>$chcrs</td>
<td>$chcrsid</td>

<td><form name='cancel_selection' class='cancel_selection' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$chcrs'>
<input type='hidden' name='crsid' class='crsid' value='$chcrsid'>
<input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>



    <button class='btn btn-cancel btn-xs' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>

    </form></td>
</tr><tbody>
```

Delete Function Code:

Function is running fine but it do not hide row which is deleted from database.

```
    <script>
$(function(){
    $('.btn.btn-cancel').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest(".cancel_selection");

        var formData =  $form.serializeArray();
        var userId =  $form.find(".user_id").val();

        var URL = "cancelselection.php";
        $.post(URL, formData).done(function(data) {


        });

        fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        });

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Which row do you want to hide?

Comment: Row which is coming in while loop and in which cancel button is clicked

Comment: You haven't added any code for a while loop.

Comment: You can set an id in jquery by: $('#elementName').attr('id', 'yourid')

Comment: @ACOMIT001 its there in my question Plz check I have mention code which is cominf from while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give unique id to row that you want to delete or hide. And using jQuery you can achieve that with that unique id.

Something like below:

HTML code

```
<table id="listData">
<tbody>
<?php while ($rowslctd=mysql_fetch_array($resultslctd)) {

$chcrs=$rowslctd['chcrs'];
$chcrsid=$rowslctd['chcrsid'];

echo"<tr id='row_selection_" .$chcrs. "'>
   <td>". $chcrs ."</td>
   <td>". $chcrsid ."</td>
<td><form name='cancel_selection_" .$chcrs. "' 
   id = 'cancel_selection_" .$chcrs. "'  
 class='cancel_selection' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='crs' class='user_id' value='$chcrs'>
<input type='hidden' name='crsid' class='crsid' value='$chcrsid'>
<input type='hidden' name='insertid' class='insertid' value='$insertid'>
<button class='btn btn-cancel btn-xs' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
</form></td>
</tr>";
<?php } ?>
<tbody>
</table>
```

On AJAX success

```
$(function(){
$('.btn.btn-cancel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest(".cancel_selection");

    var formData =  $form.serializeArray();
    var userId =  $form.find(".user_id").val();

    var URL = "cancelselection.php";
    $.post(URL, formData).done(function(data) {
        var hideId =  'table#listData tr#row_selection_' + userId;
        $(hideId).remove(); // delete 
        $(hideId).hide(); // hide
    });

    fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    });
});
});
```

Comment: but its in while loo how i can give unique id and call in ajax. Can u plz explain by editing my code.

Comment: can u help me out from this problem.??

Comment: I have updated my answer.....with an example.......
as you havn't added any while loop code or mode code... so can not give a exact solution.......

Comment: hi Can u plz help me out with one more question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874579/count-and-display-how-many-items-added-in-database-with-ajax?noredirect=1#comment72861425_42874579

Comment: naincy can u plz help me out with one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342870/if-validation-successful-hide-submit-button-and-show-loading-image/43343496#43343496

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY THIS
<tbody>
  <?php while ($rowslctd=mysql_fetch_array($resultslctd)):?>
  <tr id="row_to_hide">
     <td><?php echo $rowslctd['chcrs'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $rowslctd['chcrsid'];?></td>
     <td>
        <form>
             <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rowslctd['chcrsid'];?>">
             <button onclick="process_form($(this).closest('form'))">Cancel</button>
        </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</tbody>


<script>
    function process_form(form) {
        form.on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax('cancelselection.php',{
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(form).closest('#row_to_hide').remove();
                }
             });
         });
    }
</script>
```